# How to disable constraints primary key and foreign key while writing dataframe to AzureSQL in Databricks

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I am trying to write pyspark dataframes to Azure SQL table which has primary key and foreign key constrain. How to disable and enable those constrains in spark databricks notebook?

Comment: Where are you running Spark? How do you connect to the Azure SQL DB?

Comment: Pyspark notebook in Databricks

Comment: So I presume you are using jdbc to connect to it...

Answer (score 0):

```
%sql

ALTER TABLE my_table DROP CONSTRAINT PK_Name
USING org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc
OPTIONS (
  url "jdbc:<databaseServerType>://<jdbcHostname>:<jdbcPort>",
  dbtable "<jdbcDatabase>.atable",
  user "<jdbcUsername>",
  password "<jdbcPassword>"
)
```

Then you can enable it using

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Name PRIMARY KEY
```